# how to extract anonymous function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery funtion keydown() like below. How could I extract the inside function (e){}, and could let other elements call it or combine it to other function?

```
$("tr input[id*='txtNum']").keydown(function(e) {
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain `other elements call it or combine it to other function`

Comment: You know you don't have to write this as an anonymous function right. Write your function, say `function myKeyUp(e) {...}` then call it as your keyup handler: `$("tr input[id*='txtNum']").keydown(myKeyUp);`

Comment: besides "tr input[id*='txtNum']", "tr input[id*='txtHours']" have to use this. And "tr input[id*='txtNum']" has some other specific checking just for itself on keydown not for txtHours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have edit capabilities you could always store the function in a variable

```
var myFunction = function(e) {
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Then you can just call it inside keydown() and anywhere else you want to use it.

```
$("tr input[id*='txtNum']").keydown(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a jQuery function for this sort of thing.

Take a look at using `.triggerHandler('keydown')`. This returns the trigger handler object for your jQuery object. The trigger handler has a `handleObj` property on it, which itself has a `handler` which is the anonymous function you assigned.

In your case, `$("tr input[id*='txtNum']").triggerHandler('keydown').handleObj.handler` should give you your anonymous function.

Read more at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_triggerhandler.asp

Answer (score 0):

Assign your function to a variable and pass it to the keydown listener.  That way you can reuse and modify it as you like.

```
var keyDownListener = function(e) {
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode           < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

("tr input[id*='txtNum']").keydown(keyDownListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

the keyword is `callback function`. you can use pre-defined functions or anonymous functions for callbacks.

**general:**

```
function a(function(){
    console.log("hello");
}
a(); // logs "hello"
```

other possibility:

```
var hello = function(){
  console.log("hello");
}
function a(hello); //logss "hello" too
```

you can read more here: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

**your case:**

```
$("tr input[id*='txtNum']").keydown(function(e) {
if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

would be now:

```
var keyDownFunc = function(e) {
if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
$("tr input[id*='txtNum']").keydown(keyDownFunc);
```